# Load lengthy strings to TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I need to add two TextViews horizontally in my layout as follows, to display data from database and populate.

> TextView1_content, TextView2_content.

If the content is too long(TextView1+TextView2) to fit to the layout width, it can go to the next line, but like this.

[image]

Load first string and if not enough to type the rest, then go to next line.
I tried `android:layout_weight="1"` but it separately print both TextViews in second line, it just divide the screen in half for each text view.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one `TextView` and just populate it with `TextView1_content + TextView2_content`, something like

```
TextView.setText(TextView1_content + TextView2_content)
```

Edit: For different formatting the two values, you can use something like:

```
String content="<big><b>" + TextView1_content + "</b></big>, " + TextView2_content;
TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));
```

You can find more HTML tags supported in Android 2.1 in this article: [HTML Tags Supported By TextView](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html).

Comment: Hi Adinia, the problem is the textview1 content is going to display in bold and with a bit bigger font than the textview2. Textview2 content not going to be bold. Example: John Levis and Brothers private Limited, United Kingdom.

Comment: Edited my post with a solution for that, too.